# Changed the IP Address of Active Directory Server

Tags: active-directory

I changed the IP address of our Active Directory Server. When I open **Active Directory Users and Computers**, for example, an error message appears saying:

> The directory schema is not accessible because:
>
> An invalid directory
>   pathname was passed
>
> For this reason, the New menu may be inaccurate,
>   and the extension snap-ins may not work properly.

I am new to AD and this is the first time I encountered the error as this is also the first time that I changed the IP address. Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely just the AD related dns addresses which need updating to conform with your new ip address. Try running:

```
Nltest /dsregdns
```

on the domain controller you changed ip address for, to update dns. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786478(v=ws.10).aspx) is the complete syntax.